# I want to stack buttons with the same name but be able to call them as individuals

Tags: winforms, button, c++-cli

I want to declare one button as so: `private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  NewButton;` and then make 11 of the same button like this:

```
             int Loc=0;
             for(int i=1;i<12;i++)
             {
                 this->NewButton = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
                 this->NewButton->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
                 this->NewButton->FlatStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FlatStyle::Flat;
                 this->TheList->Controls->Add(this->NewButton);
                 this->NewButton->Location = System::Drawing::Point(-1,Loc-1);
                 this->NewButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 30);
                 this->NewButton->TabIndex = i;
                 this->NewButton->Text = L"hej"+i;
                 this->NewButton->Name = L"Button"+i;
                 this->NewButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form2::NewButton_Click);
                 Loc+=29;
             }
private: System::Void NewButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         NewButton->Text = "Hello";
     }
```

it does now not matter switch button i press to start the event but only the last button made changes it's text. is there a way to have the buttons called by maybe a number or it's name ? if not please give alternative solutions.

Comment: You only keep track of a single button, the NewButton variable stores it.  Just change its type to `List<Button^>^` and you can keep track of all of them.  Or better yet, just don't bother because it isn't necessary and use `safe_cast<Button^>(sender)` in the Click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

`NewButton` is an instance variable, so on each iteration of your loop you replace it with a different instance - only one can be saved, so that is the last one.

In the button callback when it's pressed you get `sender` as a parameter which should be the button that was pressed. So, you should use `sender` to update the text on the button rather than using `NewButton`.